# Rsyslog refuses to log over OpenVPN

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn, rsyslog

I'm trying to forward rsyslog from a client to a server over a VPN.

I have it working across an internet link already (through eth0 to an edge router) but would like it to go through the OpenVPN tunnel that goes through that same link.

I have been alternating between these directives in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file:

1. `*.*    @@50.116.x.x:6514`
2. `*.*    @@172.31.0.1:6514`

I have been inspecting the packets with `tcpdump port 6514 -nA` and for directive **1** I can see all the syslog packet going out, and [on the server] coming in.  Doing the command `telnet 50.116.x.x 6514` from the client confirms that `rsyslog` is listening.

However when I swap directive **1** for directive **2** I see nothing printed out in `tcpdump` on either side.  Running `telnet 172.31.0.1 6514` from the client side confirms that the `rsyslog` is listening on this address as well.

I ran `rsyslog -f/etc/rsyslog.conf -c3 -d` on the client in and couldn't see any obvious problems:

```
7144.035145795:b75f5b20: cfline: '*.*                   @@172.31.0.1:6514'
7144.035176137:b75f5b20:  - traditional PRI filter
7144.035191209:b75f5b20: symbolic name: * ==> 255

...snip...

7144.040606069:b75f5b20: rule 0x84deb90: rsyslog rule:
7144.040629321:b75f5b20: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
Actions:
7144.040782140:b75f5b20: builtin-fwd: 172.31.0.1
    Instance data: 0x84debe8
7144.040816265:b75f5b20:    RepeatedMsgReduction: 0
7144.040837415:b75f5b20:    Resume Interval: 30
7144.040858498:b75f5b20:    Suspended: 0
7144.040880749:b75f5b20:    Disabled: 0
7144.040904527:b75aab70: testing filter, f_pmask 255
7144.040992291:b75f5b20:    Exec only when previous is suspended: 0

...snip...

7144.107980676:b6da9b70: --------imuxsock calling select, active file descriptors (max 3): 3 
7144.331986934:b75aab70:  172.31.0.1:514/tcp
7144.332023986:b75aab70: TCP sent 87 bytes, requested 87

...snip...

7144.332313940:b75aab70: Called action, logging to builtin-fwd
7144.332321268:b75aab70: extend buf to at least 146, done 256
7144.332325242:b75aab70:  172.31.0.1
7144.332328964:b75aab70:  172.31.0.1:6514/tcp
7144.332336989:b75aab70: TCP sent 146 bytes, requested 146
7144.332341371:b75aab70: testing filter, f_pmask 0
7144.332344785:b75aab70: testing filter, f_pmask 255
```

This is really confusing... also I noticed that after the `---imuxsock` it does not use the port I specified in the config... Version details:

**Client:**

- Debian 6
- OpenVPN 2.1.3 i486-pc-linux-gnu
- rsyslog 4.6.4-2

**Server:**

- Debian 7.8
- OpenVPN 2.2.1 x86_64-linux-gnu
- rsyslog 5.8.11-3+deb7u2

Thanks for reading.

**UPDATE**

I watched `tcpdump` on the server while jumping in with netcat from the client.  When connecting over the internet with `nc 50.116.x.x 6514` I can see stuff printed in `tcpdump`.  But over the VPN with `nc 172.31.0.1 6514` nothing is printed.  Not even connect/disconnect.  But netcat never gives an error.

**UDPATE 2**

Output from `ip route`:

**Server:**

```
default via 50.116.x.1 dev eth0 
50.116.x.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 50.116.x.x 
172.31.0.0/16 via 172.31.0.2 dev tun0 
172.31.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.0.1
```

**Client:**

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev br0 
10.0.0.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.160 
172.31.0.0 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.0.133 
172.31.0.1 via 172.31.0.0 dev tun0 
192.0.2.0/24 dev dummy0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.0.2.1
```

Comment: Could you add the output from 'ip route' on both client and server please?

Comment: Added that in @Nextraztus

Comment: Are you using `tcpdump` on the tun0 interface (IIRC it defaults to eth0). What happens if you run these, `tcpdump -i tun0 port 6514` and `tcpdump port 1194` where 1194 is my asusmption for your OpenVPN connection. Finally, if your version of `tcpdump` supports it, `tcpdump -i any port 6514`. Do you see correpsonding traffic?

Comment: Ah I did not know it defaulted to eth0 @roaima, I am seeing all the syslog traffic when I change it to tun0 now.  What a silly mistake.  Thanks for that.  Now I just need to figure out why Observium is not picking it up.  Add an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcpdump` (and its replacement `tshark`) defaults to the "lowest numbered" interface. Typically this is eth0. In order to capture traffic on the OpenVPN interface tun0 you need something like this, `tcpdump -i tun0 port 6514`. (The interface name *any* can be used to capture on all interfaces.) See if you get any syslog traffic there.

Another thing to try is to see whether any traffic is being generated by OpenVPN in response to the syslog packets, `tcpdump port 1194`, where 1194 is my asusmption for your OpenVPN connection.)